# How to call a method from parent/another component

Tags: reactjs, import, local-storage, logout

The issue seems to be simple: I have a main `App` which has a log in and log out methods, among other things:

```
  onLoggedIn(authData) { // need to use both the user and the token
    console.log(authData); // authData logged in console
    this.setState({
      user: authData.user.username //authData.user.username saved in userState
    });
    // saves token and user from handleSubmit in local storage 
    localStorage.setItem('token', authData.token); 
    localStorage.setItem('user', authData.user.username);
    this.getMovies(authData.token); // retrieves films list
  }

  onLoggedOut() {
    this.setState({
      user: null
    });

    localStorage.clear();
  }
```

`onLoggedOut` is used by a navbar button (which is also a child component):

```
function MyNavbar() {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="#781820" expand="lg">
      <Navbar.Brand className="logo">
        <h1>App Name</h1>
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto">
          <Nav.Link className="text-white ml-5">Home</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
        <Form inline>
          <Button id="btn-logout" type="submit" onClick={() => this.onLoggedOut()}>Logout</Button>
        </Form>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

However, despite the fact that I have tried to import the method and/or the component into the child component:

```
import { onLoggedOut } from '../App/App;
import { App } from '../App/App';
```

the `onLoggedOut` method doesn't work. The method works (if I place the button in the main `App`, it clears the items in `localStorage`. Any of colleagues here could possible shed some light, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: see React props for passing your function to the child one level below, or React Context to pass it down any level below

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [Context Api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). I have made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/EduVencovsky/f8f6c275f42f7352571c92a59309e31d) that have a simple approach for that.

There is a simple mistake you are making

You can import a method from a class

```
import { onLoggedOut } from '../App/App';
import { App } from '../App/App';
```

I'm not sure how you are doing this import, but

- If `onLoggedOut` is inside `App`, you can't do that type of import.
- If `onLoggedOut` is outside `App`, it would never work, because it uses `this.setState`.

You need to some something that is called [`Lifting State Up`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), but for authentication, it's better to use [Context Api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). I have made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/EduVencovsky/f8f6c275f42f7352571c92a59309e31d) (it's kind of the same, but better for your case).